# Default email stretches across the screen

Tags: pantheon-mail

The default email program "Mail" has started behaving very oddly.

When I open it, it starts stretching horizontally as though it's trying to fill the screen, but it keeps going. It becomes unusable: I have to drag and drop the window several times just to get to the icon I need.

It doesn't stop expanding and just gets longer and longer, like a piece of spaghetti.

I can't see a way to delete Mail. I've installed Thunderbird, but it doesn't access my email address book like Mail did, e.g. I type two letters and it gives me all the email address containing those letters.

I need to use email a lot for my job, and am very close to abandoning eOS.

Please help!

Comment: The issue with Pantheon mail is probably related to the thread linked above.

As for autocomplete: Pantheon mail autocompletes based on the people you frequently contact, while Thunderbird autocompletes based on your address book. To get autocomplete to work on Thunderbird, you'll need to set it up to access your address book (e.g., Google Contacts). 

if you'd like more help with setting up contacts in Thunderbird, feel free to open a new thread for that question. Be sure to include the name of the email service you use. Thanks! :)

Comment: @RyanDeBeasi The first time I opened Pantheon Mail, it knew many, many contacts; it knew people I don't know. I'm accessing a work account and it seems to have access to my work address book automatically. I can't seem to configure Thunderbird or  Evolution. They will receive emails, but all fail to send them.

Comment: Follow the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1631672

Answer (score 2):

Typing **dconf reset -f /org/pantheon/mail/** into a terminal worked.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for providing that answer!